# What do "AE", "EO", and "PROD" stand for in a journal submission system?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, journal-workflow

What do "AE", "EO", "PROD" stand for in the manuscript status in journal submission systems like ScholarOne?

[image: ScholarOne Author Dashboard]

Comment: What do you mean with "in a research journal"? Where did you read these abbreviations? On a journal website? Or inside an article? Do you have a link? Is there some more context?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**AE** means *Associate Editor*: Responsible for communication with reviewers of a research manuscript.

**EO** means *Editorial Office*: The formal group/office comprising of *Editor-in-Chief* (**EIC**), and *Editorial Assistants*/*Admin Assistants*.

**PROD** means *Production Department*: Responsible for printing of articles post acceptance.

Comment: thank you coder, that is exactly what I was looking for. :)

Comment: @Pretty_Girl Welcome. Academia always has answer to such questions. It just depends on how people interpret your question, as the world is diverse with regard to languages, looks, presentations. So, never take any comments personal.(I am writing this w.r.t. your comment on closing this question.) All the best!

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please add the meaning of "ED"? I recently came across this abbreviation.